# Change out a div ID with JS or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dealing with a CMS that assigns its own id to a UL class for example

```
id="nav_1218396"
```

and I would like to replace it with

```
id="topnav"
```

Ideas?

Comment: does it assign with any perticular pattern or just random alphanumerics?

Comment: `$("[id^=nav]").attr('id','topnav');` for id starting with nav

Answer (score 6):

I think this is as simple as:

```
$('#nav_1218396').attr('id', 'topnav');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the id:

```
document.getElementById('nav_1218396').id = 'topnav';
```

but why can't you work with the ID that it already has?

Comment: The system kicks out the nav id it varies by template ID and having the js in place will help alleviate issues of re-creating more css down the road.

Comment: @Randell you shouln't just rely on this because you don't want to create more css rules, what happens if javascript is disabled?

Comment: You are right. So my be action is to adjust the CSS moving forward just to be safe?